# Frequency determination from sparsely sampled data

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics

I'm observing a sinusoidally-varying source, i.e. f(x) = a sin (bx + d) + c, and want to determine the amplitude a, offset c and period/frequency b - the shift d is unimportant. Measurements are sparse, with each source measured typically between 6 and 12 times, and observations are at (effectively) random times, with intervals between observations roughly between a quarter and ten times the period (just to stress, the spacing of observations is not constant for each source). In each source the offset c is typically quite large compared to the measurement error, while amplitudes vary - at one extreme they are only on the order of the measurement error, while at the other extreme they are about twenty times the error. Hopefully that fully outlines the problem, if not, please ask and i'll clarify.

Thinking naively about the problem, the average of the measurements will be a good estimate of the offset c, while half the range between the minimum and maximum value of the measured f(x) will be a reasonable estimate of the amplitude, especially as the number of measurements increase so that the prospects of having observed the maximum offset from the mean improve. However, if the amplitude is small then it seems to me that there is little chance of accurately determining b, while the prospects should be better for large-amplitude sources even if they are only observed the minimum number of times.

Anyway, I wrote some code to do a least-squares fit to the data for the range of periods, and it identifies best-fit values of a, b and d quite effectively for the larger-amplitude sources. However, I see it finding a number of possible periods, and while one is the 'best' (in as much as it gives the minimum error-weighted residual) in the majority of cases the difference in the residuals for different candidate periods is not large. So what I would like to do now is quantify the possibility that the derived period is a 'false positive' (or, to put it slightly differently, what confidence I can have that the derived period is correct).

Does anybody have any suggestions on how best to proceed? One thought I had was to use a Monte-Carlo algorithm to construct a large number of sources with known values for a, b and c, construct samples that correspond to my measurement times, fit the resultant sample with my fitting code, and see what percentage of the time I recover the correct period. But that seems quite heavyweight, and i'm not sure that it's particularly useful other than giving a general feel for the false-positive rate.

And any advice for frameworks that might help? I have a feeling this is something that can likely be done in a line or two in Mathematica, but (a) I don't know it, an (b) don't have access to it. I'm fluent in Java, competent in IDL and can probably figure out other things...

Comment: Two questions: Can you assume some probabilistic model for the measurement times (or, better, the time between measurements)? For each measurement you have a (noisy) value of f(x) and also an (exact) value of x ?

Comment: The measurements have been done, so times are known exactly. Some measurements were repeated, and hence there are a few relatively close pairs, but even so the separation between 'close pairs' is a significant fraction of the period. Generally the separation in measurements is a few to around ten times the period. For each measurement we have an associated error. 

The period of the sinusoid is the quantity i'd really like to recover.

Comment: Do you have a prior expectation of the period?  You could produce a plot of fit residual versus fit period, and weight this by the prior distribution.

Comment: Unfortunately the period is unknown, and poorly limited. I avoided the actual problem domain to try and keep things simple (and avoid putting people off!), but that may have been a mistake: to add some context, i'm looking at the orbital period of binary stars from radial velocity (RV) measurements. These were typically observed once a month, but some repeat measurements are separated by a few days. Orbital periods cannot be less than a few days as the stars would merge, but equally cannot be longer than tens of days as significant RV changes are seen in close-spaced observations.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Nyquist sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%2DShannon_sampling_theorem)? It might be applicable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks tailor-made for working in the frequency domain. Apply a [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) and identify the frequency based on where the power is located, which should be clear for a sinusoidal source.

ADDENDUM To get an idea of how accurate is your estimate, I'd try a [resampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29) approach such as cross-validation. I think this is the direction that you're heading with the Monte Carlo idea; lots of work is out there, so hopefully that's a wheel you won't need to re-invent.

Comment: I have tried this with a variety of period searches (e.g. Lomb-Scargle or string length), but I have the same problem - the sampling is too poor to suppress false peaks in the periodogram, so I cannot positively identify the correct period. It seems the best I can do in the majority of cases is highlight the strongest periodicity and - if possible - give a confidence level. Which I don't know how to do :)

Comment: @strmqm - Ah, I didn't realize you were working in the frequency domain.

Comment: Thanks, that resampling link looks very useful - I hadn't come across that before. Will experiment. I'm not explicitly working in the frequency domain, rather i've just partially explored a number of avenues to try to make progress.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to do what might seem at first to make the problem more difficult. Rewrite f in the similar form:

```
f(x) = a1*sin(b*x) + a2*cos(b*x) + c
```

This is based on the identity for the sin(u+v).

Recognize that if b is known, then the problem of estimating {a1, a2, c} is a simple LINEAR regression problem. So all you need to do is use a 1-variable minimization tool, working on the value of b, to minimize the sum of squares of the residuals from that linear regression model. There are many such univariate optimizers to be found.

Once you have those parameters, it is easy to find the parameter a in your original model, since that is all you care about.

```
a = sqrt(a1^2 + a2^2)
```

The scheme I have described is called a partitioned least squares.

Comment: Thanks, I may have been unclear as the period b is the quantity i'm most interested in, amplitude and offset can be estimated quite accurately from the overall range of the data. The period may be substantially incorrect if my least-squares fit locks on to a false period, so i'm really looking to gain a feel for what confidence I can have in my determination of 'b'. Ideally I would have dozens of measurements spanning a single complete cycle, but I can't do that.

Comment: But you do get the period when you do the estimation. What is b? It is the value at which the sum of squares is minimized. Confidence estimation is more difficult, since this requires you use a tool to compute that from a nonlinear regression model. It is easy enough to do though using standard techniques.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reasonable estimate of the size and the nature of your noise (e.g. white Gaussian with SD sigma), you can

(a) invert the Hessian matrix to get an estimate of the error in your position and

(b) should be able to easily derive a significance statistic for your fit residues.

For (a), compare http://www.physics.utah.edu/~detar/phys6720/handouts/curve_fit/curve_fit/node6.html
For (b), assume that your measurement errors are independent and thus the variance of their sum is the sum of their variances.